¿Cómo cambio el fondo de un entry en python?,no solo quiero cambiar el color, quiero poner una imágen, se puede, alguien ha tenido la misma situación?
tengo este caso, quiero que el campo entry no tenga fondo y de tenerlo quiero que sea la imagen que se elija en el proceso de random, no quiero cambiar el color del fondo, quiero o ponerlo transparente o poner la imagen, ya lo he intentado ampliando e insertando uno en el otro pero lo único que logro es que uno se sobreponga al otro.
def Ventana_interacción():
interacción = Tk()
interacción.geometry("500x400")

color1="#AE5FE2"
color2="#5FE2D5"
color3="#FD1706"

Frame(interacción,border=5,relief="groove",bg=color1).place(relx=0,rely=0, relwidth=1,relheight=1)

Label(interacción,text="Traductor",bg=color1,fg=color3,font="Elephant 25 bold").place(relx=0.5,rely=0.125, anchor="center")
Frame2=Frame(interacción,border=5,relief="groove",bg=color2).place(relx=0.07,rely=0.25,relwidth=0.86,relheight=0.65)

flor1 = "ruta_imagen"
flor2 = "ruta_imagen"
flor3 = "ruta_imagen"
flor4 = "ruta_imagen"
flor5 = "ruta_imagen"
flor6 = "ruta_imagen"
flor7 = "ruta_imagen"
flor8 = "ruta_imagen"
flor9 = "ruta_imagen"

# Lista de imágenes
flores = [flor1, flor2, flor3, flor4, flor5, flor6, flor7, flor8, flor9]

# Seleccionar una flor al azar
flor = random.choice(flores)

# Cargar la imagen
flor_image = Image.open(flor)
flor_image = flor_image.resize((421, 250))  # Redimensionar la imagen

# Convertir la imagen a un objeto compatible con Tkinter
flor_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(flor_image)

# Crear un widget Label para mostrar la imagen
label_flor = Label(Frame2, image=flor_tk, bg=color2)
label_flor.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor="center")

# Crear el cuadro de entrada con el tamaño deseado
entry = Entry(Frame2, width=50, font=("Arial", 16))  # Ajustar el ancho y fuente
entry.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.85, anchor="center")  # Posicionar el Entry en el Frame2

interacción.mainloop()

Ventana_interacción()
